# Spring boot - Serve static file based on request url / host

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I currently have a spring boot application, but I would like to serve static content based on URL host requiring the content:

For example:

- If the request comes from "www.app1.com", I will serve the content from the directory src/main/webapp/app1/
- If the request comes from "www.app2.com", Ii will serve the content from the directory src/main/webapp/app2/

How can I reach this using the Spring Boot framework?

Comment: No. you can't do that simple way. You could look into this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29359254/simple-reverse-proxy-with-spring-boot-and-netflix-zuul

Comment: the best option is setup a reverse proxy like `nginx` for such routing